# Specifiy input targeted blur function

Tags: javascript, jquery

My function works as it should. is there a way to remove the function from a specific input? Because it changes all inputs.. i have 2 check boxes and 1 input that i need to not have this function on.

```
$('input').blur(function(){
    $('input').parent().removeClass("gray");
})
    .focus(function() {     
        $(this).parent().addClass("gray")
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by specific input ?

Comment: Aftab Ahmed i want this on all my input fields.. but i have 3 input fields i dont want this function

Comment: do you have id's or class of those 3 inputs to distinguish them from rest in DOM ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a class to the input and checkbox that you don't want the `onblur` functions, then update the code as below

Add the `class` to the three inputs that you don't want this feature

```
$('input').not( ".class" ).blur(function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("gray");
  })
  .focus(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass("gray")
  });
```

Hope this helps what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Use `this` context, `$('input')` will select all the `<input>` elements, `this` in the `callback` will hold the element on which `event` is invoked!

```js
$('input').blur(function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("gray");
  })
  .focus(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass("gray")
  });
```

```css
.gray {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Rayon not sure what you meant

Answer (score 0):

If you have id's for those three inputs you can use this code snippet.

```
$('input').blur(function(){
    $(this).parent().removeClass("gray");
 })
.focus(function() {     
    $(this).parent().not( "#id1, #id2, #id3" ).addClass("gray")
 });
```

It will add class to those inputs which do not match the selector.